# Average every n element of axis 1 in a 3D numpy ndarray

Tags: multidimensional-array, mean, numpy-ndarray

I have a 3D numpy of shape `(900,10,54)`.
And I want to average the values of every two elements into one, for axis `1`.

Expected outcome would have shape: `(900,5,54)`.

Answer (score 3):

**One way to do this**:

This uses numpy array [slicing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing) to achieve this.

```py
import numpy as np
x = np.random.rand(900, 10, 64)
y = (x[:, ::2, :] + x[:, 1::2, :]) / 2
```

**Another approach**:

If you have a variable number of consecutive elements in `axis = 1` that you want to sum (which was `2` above), you can use `reshape` and `mean` to achieve this.

```py
n = 2
y = x.reshape(x.shape[0], x.shape[1] // n, n, x.shape[2]) # shape = (900, 5, 2, 64)
y = y.mean(axis = 2)
```

This sums consecutive `n` rows for each of inner matrices in your 3D array `x`.